# Stack Walking a debugged process

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, callstack

I'm opened opening a process (with C++/Windows) using

```
if( CreateProcessA( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
   (LPSTR)path, //argv[1],        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    creationFlags,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &startInfo,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &processInfo )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

where

```
DWORD creationFlags = DEBUG_PROCESS | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS;
```

and then I'm trying to stackwalk it with

```
bool ok = StackWalk64(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386,m_ps.Handle ,m_th.Handle, 
    &m_stackframe, &m_threadContext,
    0, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

but stackwalk just gives me the top address and the next one is 0, while I *know* there are more addresses in the stack.

Does anybody know what's the problem?
thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops...  I forget to call "ContinueDebugEvent" after receiving events from the debugged process - so it stayed paused and the StackWalk was infact correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell based on this snippet.  There's so much you have to set up correctly in order for this to work.  Check out the logic at [this detailed blog post](http://jpassing.com/2008/03/12/walking-the-stack-of-the-current-thread/).

Post more code if you can post a bigger but not too big sample.  How are you setting up the STACKFRAME and CONTEXT structures? Are you looping on `StackWalk64`?  Any given call only returns one stack frame.

Comment: I already had this working well when I created the process only with the " CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE" flag, but now I need to stackwalk a debugged process. the flags in "CreateProcess" are the only differences I've made...