# How to see C++ stack trace for assert failure in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, assert

How can I see the stacktrace when my assert fails in visual studio 2012? If I am attahed to a process, it works as expected, but when I just build using F5 (debug), my assert happens, giving me the "Abort, Retry, Ignore" prompt, but I don't see my callstack in the debugger.

Is there any way to enable it during debug builds, or will I always have to build and then attach to the process?

My assert is just a simple assert(1 == 2) to get it to fail and see the callstack.

Comment: Pressing `Retry` doesn't produce a callstack?

Comment: Well, that was a question well spent.... Yeah, that worked perfectly. Thanks! I wonder why they make you click retry before breaking.

Comment: "Stack Walking" for process debugging was discussed in Stack Overflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224307/stack-walking-a-debugged-process

Answer (score 11):

<sub>(Reposting from comment)</sub>

Pressing the `Retry` button will activate the debugger, allowing you to see your callstack, locals, etc.